# Can't download documentation for android

Tags: android, linux, android-studio

Using Android Studio I cannot download the reference documetation for android. This means that all attempts to use Quick Documentation either take too long or fail outright as Android Studio fetchs the documentation remotly. I have searched for a solution, but cannot find any post with a similar problem.
Most similar issues suggest using Android Studios's SDK manager (`Tools` > `SDK Manager`) and selecting `Documentation for Android` under the tools tab, however that is not there for me.

I have tried restarting (android studio & computer) invalidating caches redownloading entire SDK versions. Nothing has worked. I have a very slow and inconsistent internet connection every time I use Ctrl+Q it takes 10-30 seconds to load and often fails.

This is slowing me down a lot as I am not that familiar with Android's API

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChMWN.png)

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you found a solution at the end?

Comment: No, no solution yet